# How to insert a Python Plotted Graph to HTML file?

Tags: python, html

I had been searching for ways to do this but I seem couldn't get any helpful answer online thus I have to directly ask here.

What I want is simple: Process some data from CSV, plot it into graph and post it to my HTML. I do not own any web-domain, the HTML is put in a shared drive and could be view by a certain allowed crowd using Chrome.

Here is my python code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import plotly as py
import numpy as np
import plotly.tools as plotly_tools
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

def dashboard_plot_graph():
    html_template = __Html_path__.get_template("PublishPG.html")
    curr_mcl_res = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(__Result_path__, __Chart_csv__))
    print curr_mcl_res.head()
    x = curr_mcl_res['TestSuite']
    my_plot = curr_mcl_res.plot(x, kind='bar', stacked=True, title='Latest Trend')
    fig = my_plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig("./my_img.png")
    html_template_vars = {"curr_mcl_div_placeholder": curr_mcl_res.to_html()}
    html_out = html_template.render(html_template_vars)
    f = open ('file.html', 'w')
    f.write( html_out )
    f.close()
    plt.show()
```

Here is my HTML code snippet:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Testing Webpage </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Hello World! </h1>
<p> This is a test page </p>
{{ curr_mcl_div_placeholder }}
</body>

<html>
```

This is the plot I wish to see in my webpage:
[image]

I have tried:

1. Follow online tutorial which seem to say plotly able to insert the plot to HTML... however it failed... the most I can do is to
   insert the data frame (table) as shown in the code snippet above.
2. I tried to think work around such as save the plotted graph as image and try to insert the image to html. But it does not allow to
   take image from local drive for security reason. It only able to
   pull image if I uploaded the image somewhere to the cloud /
   web-domain. But the data is not suitable to be exposed on any social
   media site.

Any suggest for me to get through this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

I recently did a [Google Map project](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/03/how-to-plot-cycling-route-using-google-maps-api-and-flask-web-framework/) by plotting a matplotlib generated chart on a web page without using Bokeh and without saving the file into hard disk (as it is slow when involving hardware i/o).

I also chose to plot the graph in svg instead of png, as svg is valid html that can be easily inject into html template.

Python standard library has `io.BytesIO` object for writing binary streams, such as images, to a buffer in memory with the same syntax as used for writing binary data to files. The idea is to let Matplotlib write to a `io.BytesIO` object in the memory and afterwards retrieve the series of bytes in the plot file from this object and embed it in the HTML file directly.

```
 from io import BytesIO

 # prepare your plt.plot here as you normally do
 svg_file = BytesIO()
 plt.savefig(svg_file, format='svg')     # save the file to io.BytesIO
 svg_file.seek(0)
 svg_data = svg_file.getvalue().decode() # retreive the saved data
 svg_data = '<svg' + svg_data.split('<svg')[1]   # strip the xml header
```

The saved SVG image contain the xml header which we don't need it so I split the header and only keep the part that started with `<svg` tag.

You can then add svg_data directly in your template like this:

```
{{ svg_data|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/), it's an amazing framework.

[Here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#bars-and-rectangles) some instructions for the graph you're looking to do

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, if you just want to move on, is that you don't insert an image directly into HTML, but instead make a reference to the image file. Something like:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Testing Webpage </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Hello World! </h1>
<p> This is a test page </p>
<img src="my_img.png" title="My plot" />
</body>

<html>
```

But Gsk's suggestion has a lot of merit.